# Is there a LaTeX package that contains an environment for excursions and digressions?

Tags: packages, environments

Is there a convenient LaTeX package that can be included in the preamble and allows to write more or less extended excursions/digressions by using commands like:

```
\begin{excursion}

extended explanations and digressions to a topic mentioned in the main text

\end{excursion}
```

or something like that?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you mean? As such, people like me don't know what it is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What do you want this to look like? You can define your own environments, but I do not know, how an excursion should behave in your document. Please give us a minimal code of your document.

Comment: As the two people above say: Show us how it should look like and we can tell you how to do it (if we know). Remember we do not own a crystal ball ;)

Comment: Something like `\begin{texcursion}...`? ;-)

Comment: For the digressions in my own writing, I use `\begin{comment} ... \end{comment}` from the `comment` package. ;)

Comment: @AndrewCashner. I don't think that the comment package can handle what the OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: @Ludenticus I was making a bad joke. In other words, I try to omit digressions from my writing.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I use `\footnote{...}` and then try to remove as many footnotes as possible later on.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear what the expected output should look like, but you can draw a box for short «digressions».

[Edited: I'm updating my answer following @Manuel's suggestion]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{A Great Title}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More easily and robustly done with `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Manuel You are right. I updated my answer